# SSMS New Database Diagram using cached data?

Tags: ssms

When I try to use the New Database Diagram tool in SSMS, it appears to use old cached table data. Columns and keys that I have dropped from tables somehow continue to appear in the diagram. When I select the tables for the diagram, I hit the Refresh button, but the problem still occurs.

I have checked [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] and the dropped columns are not there anymore. I have refreshed the Object Explorer as well, by right clicking the database and selecting "Refresh".

How can I force the tool to clear its cache? Or is something else happening?

Comment: Refresh the object explorer.

Comment: @Larnu I should have mentioned that I had tried that. I've edited the post. Thank you.

Comment: Have you refreshed intellisense as well; pretty sure that the database diagrams uses the object explorer, but worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to restart the application.